# Can we get upload progress in ria services when uploading the photo?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am using RIA services with Silverlight 4.0. I took a picture from the webcam. Now i want to upload that picture to the server. I could use [Invoke] with RIA Services and that would work fine. However, i want to show the real time progress bar to the user (not just the busy indicator). I want to show the % of the bytes uploaded on the server. How can i do so ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would probably be splitting the file into smaller chunks and then sending these in a loop. If you split a 1 MB image into 100 parts of 10KB, you would have a nice progress bar with 100 steps.

Someone else described [how to upload files in chunks](http://endofstream.com/uploading-files-from-silverlight-client-using-wcf-ria-services/) with lots of details.